# Unable to insert an html link to common error codes in swagger 2.0 documentation

Tags: java, json, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger 2.0 for my API documentation. In addition to model schema definition for possible error codes, I need and html link which refer to an external url (which actually lists out the details about all the possible error codes, of my API).

**What I have :**

[image]

**While I'm trying to have something like this :**

[image]

which includes an html link, just below the model schema definition.

**What I tried :** 
I expected this link to be a result of 'external-docs' annotation, and when I checked the generated html, and the json data, they indeed contained the 'external-docs' element.

But even on putting the annotation @ExternalDocs on my implementer class, i do not get any corresponding reference (neither on swagger UI nor on swagger json). I also tried to put the external-doc reference through swagger configuration through servlet, but it didn't work either?

**Annotation Reference :**

```
@GET <br>
@Path("/v2/hotspots") <br>
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) <br>
@ExternalDocs(value="Common Error Codes", url = "some url") <br>
@ApiOperation(....)<br>
@ApiResponses(....)<br>
public final Response someMethod( ) <br>
```

**Code Reference :**

```
ExternalDocs exterDoc = new ExternalDocs();
exterDoc.setDescription("Common Error Codes");
exterDoc.setUrl("some url");

Swagger swag = new Swagger();
swag.externalDocs(exterDoc);

beanConfig.configure(swag );
```

While other properties of beanConfig are loaded successfully, the external-docs doesn't get reflected.

**Version Details :** 
Swagger 2.0 (1.5.3-M1) 
Jersey 2.17 
Java 7

What is the correct way to include an html link like this into swagger docs? Am I doing something wrong for including the external-docs?

Any help or suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance !!